# Как проверить пустой ли файл csv Python

Tags: python, csv

В некоторых ситуация программа ничего не добавляет в файл csv, данные из которого (если они есть) должны использоваться в следующих шагах. Как перед следующим шагом проверить есть ли что-то в файле?

```
with open("itog.csv", newline='') as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: проверить, пустой ли файл или нет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-empty-or-not

Comment: Файл из пробелов пустой или нет?

Comment: На правах догадки: по количеству элементов в списке `readlines()` если предполагается что заголовки полей в "пустом" файле должны присутствовать то количество элементов будет == 1 для "пустого" файла. Если же не предполагается наличие строки заголовков то == 0. Но если в пустом файле могут быть и заголовки и строки из одних разделителей тогда уже надо по другому

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os
print(os.stat("file").st_size == 0)
```

> `True`
>   или `False`